# Access Function returning JsonResult class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

My function is returning JsonResult class. My code is as below:-

```
public JsonResult UpdateTest(string a, int b, string c, string d, string e, bool f)
    {
         try
        {
            theService.UpdateTest(a,b,c,d,e,f);
            return Json(new { result = true });
        }
        catch (Exception myException)
        {
            LogError(SECTION, myException);
            Response.StatusCode = AjaxError();
            return Json(new { result = false });
        }
    }
```

I want to access the value of  **return Json(new { result = true })** while creating my Unit Test Cases.

Please tell how can I do that, please provide the code.

Thanks,
 Rahul